# Outlook filter mailing list alerts

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do you filter outlook mailing list alerts?

Since this took me quite awhile to figure out I hope this will help other people. Sometimes you are a part of an outlook mailing list that constantly sends out alerts. If you want to filter these emails to another folder you can not simply filter the email address. If you do it will filter all emails from any member of this mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to filter these emails:

- click rules button,
- create rule,
- check from,
- check subject contains,
- add useful words for the alert,
- check move item to folder,
- set folder.
- click ok to save